# Global UI tracking of the keyboard focus

Tags: keyboard, focus

Be interested in knowing what the opinion is regarding what API / application type to use to tracking the keyboard focus on the windows desktop.  I have tried the FocusTracker from the samples targeting .NET 4.7.2 in the [netframework](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/netframework). It uses the  Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(OnFocusChanged) event. This mostly worked but had issues when setting focus to FireFox.  It would start to loss track and not report FireFox focus or any other focus point after that and eventually would throw an exception.  Ignoring the exception, it would start to work again on applications other then FireFox.

So which should one use .Net, win32 api, WPF, UWP, etc.  API sets.

The goal here is to make use of an RGB LED keyboard by having it light the hotkeys with a certain color including the modifier (shift, ctrl, alt) hotkeys.  This would be a reminder of the hotkeys between the different CAD tools. So with Logitech SDK, one can set the key light colors dynamically.  The though was to track the keyboard focus and then update the chosen key light colors when the modifier hotkey is pressed.  Logitech's tool already allows you to customize the key light colors for each desired application.  Just does not allow for modifier key based customization.  Thanks.

As requested here is the code snippet:

```
 /// <summary>
        ///     Initialization.
        /// </summary>
        private void Startup()
        {
            Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(OnFocusChanged);
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Retrieves the top-level window that contains the specified
        ///     UI Automation element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="element">The contained element.</param>
        /// <returns>The  top-level window element.</returns>
        private AutomationElement GetTopLevelWindow(AutomationElement element)
        {
            var walker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
            AutomationElement elementParent;
            var node = element;
            try // In case the element disappears suddenly, as menu items are 
                // likely to do.
            {
                if (node == AutomationElement.RootElement)
                {
                    return node;
                }
                // Walk up the tree to the child of the root.
                while (true)
                {
                    elementParent = walker.GetParent(node);
                    if (elementParent == null)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    if (elementParent == AutomationElement.RootElement)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    node = elementParent;
                }
            }
            catch (ElementNotAvailableException)
            {
                node = null;
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
                node = null;
            }
            return node;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Handles focus-changed events. If the element that received focus is
        ///     in a different top-level window, announces that. If not, just
        ///     announces which element received focus.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="src">Object that raised the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
        private void OnFocusChanged(object src, AutomationFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var elementFocused = src as AutomationElement;
                var topLevelWindow = GetTopLevelWindow(elementFocused);
                if (topLevelWindow == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                // If top-level window has changed, announce it.
                if (topLevelWindow != _lastTopLevelWindow)
                {
                    _lastTopLevelWindow = topLevelWindow;
                    Console.WriteLine("Focus moved to top-level window:");
                    Console.WriteLine("  " + topLevelWindow.Current.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Announce focused element.
                    Console.WriteLine("Focused element: ");
                    Console.WriteLine("  Type: " +
                                      elementFocused.Current.LocalizedControlType);
                    Console.WriteLine("  Name: " + elementFocused.Current.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            catch (ElementNotAvailableException)
            {
            }

        }
```

Update:  I did run this code again for a while an it worked without throwing an exception even with Firefox this time but the sound to speakers died. Not sure if this is linked.  Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of what you're using? It's not clear exactly what you're trying.

Comment: As requested here is the code snippet: